# How to improve access time/ memory for storing a big hash in perl

Tags: perl, search, hash

I have a very large Perl hash has which contains ~600M entries (integer values). I was wondering if there is a limit for the number of entries in a hash. Also given this hash is so big, it requires a lot of memory and time to load. Does anyone have a suggestion for looking up data in a faster way? Would it be faster to store the data in an array/ hash?

The goal of the project is to find if the value is present in a list or not (and then downstream analysis)? Does anything have a suggestion for quick search in Perl?

--Diviya

Comment: perl imposes no limit on the length of lists and hashes besides the obvious memory limit. If the hashing is no longer working for you, you may try a database as has been proposed by others or replace the hash-search by an in-memory tree like Tree::Binary::Search. The moment you want to cache parts of the tree on the disk: This is what databases are really good at.

Answer (score 2):

Store data in some key-value database like [Redis](http://redis.io).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your data should be on a database. If you use `SQLite` then there is no need to install and run a driver process. The data can stay in the database file and be interrogated by a single database query.

Comment: You will need [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) and the driver module [`DBD::SQLite`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::SQLite) installed. Nothing else. You may have these already.